# Рекурсивный метод вывода в паттерне компоновщика на основе двумерного массива

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования, компоновщик

Здравствуйте, помогите реализовать рекурсивный алгоритм вывода всех элементов.
Пример вывода: [1,2.0,false,[1,2],4.2,[1,[2],true]], где [] контейнер.
Возможно, нужно начать с вершины, выводим содержимое контейнера, если снова встречается контейнер углубляемся, так до конца. Но с чего начать? Даже не представляю, как нужно перегрузить методы для елемента и контейнера

upd: ОП ушел спать, будет утром

```
class base
{
public:
    virtual bool Equals(base *n) = 0;
    virtual void ToString(char* bufer) = 0;
    virtual ~base() {}
};

class element : public base
{
public:
    union {
        int iVar;
        float fVar;
        bool bVar;
    };
public:

    element(int var) { iVar = var; }
    element(float var) { fVar = var; }
    element(bool var) { bVar = var; }
    bool Equals(base* n) {
        element* p = dynamic_cast<element*>(n);
        if (bVar == p->bVar || fVar == p->fVar || iVar == p->iVar) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    bool operator == (element* n)
    {
        if (bVar == n->bVar || fVar == n->fVar || iVar == n->iVar) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    void ToString(char* buffer) {

    }
};

class container : public base
{
public:
private:
    base*** array;
    int order;
    int ni; int nj; //последний элемент
public:
    container(int ord) {
        ni = 0; nj = 0;
        order = ord;
        array = new base**[order];
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            array[i] = new base*[order];
            for (int j = 0; j < order; j++) {
                array[i][j] = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    ~container() {
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            if (array[i]) {
                delete[] array[i];
            }
            delete[] array;
            array = NULL;
            order = 0;
        }
    }
    bool Add(base *n) { //добавление элемента в конец
        array[ni][nj] = n;
        if (nj != order - 1) {
            nj++;
            return true;
        }
        else if (nj == order - 1 && ni != order - 1) {
            nj = 0; ni++;
        }
        else if (nj == order - 1 && ni == order - 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool Equals(base* n) {
        container* p = dynamic_cast<container*>(n);
        bool full = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < order; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] != p->array[i][j]) {
                    full = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return full;
    }
    void ToString(char* buffer) {
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам точно нужно именно такое представление - с `union`, тройным указателем `base***` и т.д.?

Написать же рекурсивный вывод достаточно просто. Проверяете свой `base`. Если это `element`, просто выводите его и возвращаетесь. Если это `container` - выводите `[`, затем выполняете проход по всем элементам в нем, вызывая для каждого функцию вывода. По окончании - `]`. С запятыми сами разберетесь :)

Как вы будете определять, что именно из объединения сейчас в вашем элементе и как его выводить - не знаю, разве что добавляйте дополнительное поле.

А вообще - все это напоминает попытки связать веревочками разные части велосипеда в надежде получить мотоцикл. Например, для начала ответьте на вопросы:

- Чем оправдано применение именно `union`?
- Зачем данные в классе сделаны `public`?
- Что произойдет, если при приведении `dynamic_cast` ваш указатель будет не тем, что вы ожидали?
- Так ли необходим `base***array`? Может, стоит воспользоваться каким-то стандартным контейнером?
- Вы не находите ненадежной проверку `if (bVar == p->bVar || fVar == p->fVar || iVar == p->iVar)`? Что если младший байт совпадает у разных целых чисел, например?...

Comment: union - условие задания. да, классы надо в приват. base*** array - двумерный массив. Бибилиотеку STL нельзя использовать... над остальным надо подумать)

Comment: Классы в приват не получится, использую их в мейне